# No mobile and/or iOS options in RAD Studio XE4

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I have Installed Rad Studio XE4 Update 1, but can't not find option of FireMoney Mobile Application, is there anything I need to setup before I can see those options?

(XE4 Version is 18.0.4905.60485)

Comment: Which edition? Starter,Professional, Enterprise? If below Enterprise did you purchase the mobile add-on?

Comment: If you go to `File > New` and you cannot see `FireMonkey Mobile Application` then you did not purchase the mobile add-on and there-for cannot use FMX mobile development.

Comment: Rad Studio Pro and above should have support for iOS.

Comment: i am using the Architect

Comment: Then perhaps at install time you unchecked the mobile add-on? Try reinstalling.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a vendor support question related to product installation. Embarcadero offers [free technical support](http://support.embarcadero.com) for installation-related problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart the setup and input the serial number for the mobile addon. Here you can read the details:
http://snaptip.com/j2tvjergt0/how-to-install-delphi-xe4-pro-mobile-addon